# How to find package equivalents of 14.04 (trusty) in 18.04 (bionic)

Tags: 18.04, migration

I am migrating our software from Trusty to Bionic. On trusty, there were many dependencies which were manually installed, but many of those were removed/renamed in Xenial itself and not available on Bionic. For e.g., `gdb-minimal`, `python-support` etc. Is there any easy way to find the equivalent packages for these, on Bionic ? Or, will some of them have to built for Bionic if they are mandatory ?

Comment: Maybe you need to consult the developer of the software in question?

Comment: It would be easier back when 14.04 LTS still appeared in searches (wasn't EOL as https://packages.ubuntu.com/ doesn't provide 14.04 answers anymore), meaning you may need to go and look up manually in launchpad (eg. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-support  for python-support)

Comment: You, the human, will need to figure out the appropriate path forward for each mystery package. Some might simply be renamed. `gdb-minimal` can usually be replaced by ordinary `gdb`. Python packages (like `python-support` should be updated to Py3, as Py2 is deprecated and will be dropped (by Python.org) in 2020. There is no single answer - every package may have a different right solution for you.